# Menu items doesn't show up on the actionbar using Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

The previous stackoverflow questions on this exact title are "old".

Android Studio 1.4

API Level 16

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1

I've created an empty activity and added the following menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Search" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Compose" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_compose1"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Compose" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_compose2"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Compose" />
```

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onCreateOptionsMenu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In the Android Studio designer, I see the two icons and a ... menu icon.

[image: In Android Studio Designer]

But when I launch the app in the emulator, all I see is the two icons and no overflow ... menu icon.

[image]

When I hit the Menu button, then I see the additional entries though.

https://github.com/danvallejo/actionbar

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to change the namespace 'app' to to yourApp: 
xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" and yourApp:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Comment: It made no difference.

Comment: I had the same issue. I just opened sdk manager and updated 'Android Support Repository' to version 24. This worked for me. If it still does not work, try updating 'Android Support Library' 'Google Play Services' and 'Google Repository' too.

Comment: It still made no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use the support library Toolbar and to modify the AndroidManifest to change the them to @style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:elevation="4dp"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```