# Android Menu Not displaying

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried to find solution and recreate Menu from this post (Contain Solution)

[Menu items doesn't show up on the actionbar using Android Studio 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250422/menu-items-doesnt-show-up-on-the-actionbar-using-android-studio-1-4)

but it displaying Menu like completely black Screen

this is my code

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
        android:icon="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Compose" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose1"
        android:icon="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Compose" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose2"
        android:icon="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Compose" />

</menu>
```

Activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package testproject.example.com.sensor_new;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreateOptionsMenu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


}
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="testproject.example.com.sensor_new">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <permission
        android:name="testproject.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have even applied the style theme as given in the solution , But still I am not getting menu ,

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have not initialized the toolbar.

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

add the above code to your `onCreate` method

Comment: it says "cannot resolve method setSupportActionBar(toolbar);"....... i imported android.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: should I remove it ?

Comment: Extend MainActivity from AppCompatActivity, not Activity. Then setSupportActionBar will work.

Note that your theme must be defined with the parent theme "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar".

Comment: even after removal of setSupportActionBar(toolbar) .. I am not getting Menu

Comment: @Denny ...got it .. this is my answer

Comment: sorry for late response...but now problem is resolved. replace activity with AppCompactActivity

Answer (score 2):

do this thing

**1.** make sure that `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.widget.Toolbar`

**2.** change this `Activity` to `AppCompactActivity`.

**3.** make sure that in style your parent theme
    `"Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: @NeerajVerma glad to help you. and I improve my format so it help other.